# FluentNHibernate SQL Server configuration; connectionstring problem

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

It's my first attempt on Fluent NH. I store the connection string in Properties.Settings;

```
FnhDbString = Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FNHTest;Integrated Security=True
```

If I configure Fluent with `.FromAppSetting` I get exception:

```
ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Data Source
```

If I configure Fluent with `.FromConnectionStringWithKey` I get exception:

```
NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The full method:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{ 
      return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
        .ConnectionString(c => c
            .FromAppSetting(Properties.Settings.Default.FnhDbString))
        .Cache(c => c
            .UseQueryCache()).ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>())
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

...

So what am I doing wrong here..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
.ConnectionString(c => c.FromAppSetting(Properties.Settings.Default.FnhDbString))
```

to this:

```
.ConnectionString(Properties.Settings.Default.FnhDbString)
```

Comment: I'm curious why this worked?  I have a similar problem using the lamba syntax that apparently doesnt work?  Trying to use the ConnectionStringFromKey method

Comment: That worked because `FromAppSetting` needs a `appSetting` key value which you can access using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];`. Secondly, he was directly passing the value of the key `FnhDbString` from resources, i.e. the connection string, to the `FromAppSetting` method, which obviously fails. Just passing the connection string directly to the parent method words without issues.